# How do I examine the behavior of the Reciprocal Multifactorial Series $\Sigma \frac{1}{n!^{(k)}}$ as k approaches infinity.

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, gamma-function

This question is a direct continuation of my previous question.

[How to prove the formula for the Reciprocal Multifactorial constant?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3993774/how-to-prove-the-formula-for-the-reciprocal-multifactorial-constant)

User *metamorphy* provided a lucid proof for the closed form equation of the Reciprocal Multifactorial Constant. And also a statement on its asymptote as k approaches infinity. Which is as follows:

> $m(k)=1+e^{1/k}(H_k-\Delta_k)\ \text{and,}\\ 
> > \Delta_k=\frac1k\underbrace{\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{1-t^{1/k}}t^{1/k}\frac{1-e^{-t/k}}{t}\,dt}_{\text{has
> > a finite $k\to\infty$ limit}}\underset{k\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}0.$

I was aware that the Reciprocal Multifactorial would eventually approach a harmonic series due to the definition of a multifactorial, which is as follows:

> $n!^{(k)} =   \begin{cases}
> 1 & \text{if $n=0$} \\
> n & \text{if $0<n\leq k$} \\   n\left((n-k)!^{(k)}\right) & \text{if $n>k$}   \end{cases}$

As k approaches infinity the $k^{th}$ multifactorial will tend towards the natural numbers. And the reciprocal series would approach $1+H_k$

However I am asking this question to know how to prove this using the closed form formula as *metamorphy* did in the previous question. I wasn't able to solve it myself.

*Unrelated: Do you think there are any other interesting properties about this series worth examining, since I've found it quite interesting?*

Comment: Your actual question is not clear to me. Are you asking how metamorphy is arguing $\Delta_k \to 0$? It looks like the integrand is strictly increasing on $[0, 1]$, so the maximum is at $t=1$. In that case, the $k \to \infty$ limit works out to be $k(1-e^{-1/k})$, which itself has limit $1$ as $k \to \infty$. So, the integrand is basically bounded by $1$. You can make this more precise, or find your own analysis of the integrand, if that's what you're interested in.

Comment: I understood why $\Delta_k$ approaches zero. I meant how do I derive $m(k)=1+e^{1/k}(H_k-\Delta_k)$ for k approaches infinity from the general form of $m(k)=1+\frac{e^{1/k}}k\sum_{r=1}^k k^{r/k}\int_0^{1/k}x^{r/k-1}e^{-x}\,dx$. Hope this clarifies it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have to answer it myself. Let the point of departure be $$m(k)=1+\frac{e^{1/k}}{k}\sum_{r=1}^k\int_0^1 t^{r/k-1}e^{-t/k}\,dt,$$ appearing in my [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3994064) immediately before the substitution $t=kx$.

The statement being discussed just comes from $e^{-t/k}=1-(1-e^{-t/k})$: $$\int_0^1 t^{r/k-1}e^{-t/k}\,dt=\frac{k}{r}-\int_0^1 t^{r/k-1}(1-e^{-t/k})\,dt,$$ giving $m(k)=1+e^{1/k}(H_k-\Delta_k)$ as written: $$\Delta_k=\frac1k\int_0^1\left(\sum_{r=1}^k t^{r/k}\right)\frac{1-e^{-t/k}}{t}\,dt=\frac1k\int_0^1\frac{(1-t)(1-e^{-t/k})}{t(t^{-1/k}-1)}\,dt.$$

---

For curiosity, here's the asymptotics of $\Delta_k$ in more detail:

\begin{align*}
\Delta_k&=\frac1k f\Big(\frac1k\Big),\\
f(\lambda)&=\int_0^1\frac{(1-t)(1-e^{-\lambda t})}{t(e^{-\lambda\log t}-1)}\,dt\asymp\sum_{n=0}^{(\infty)}a_n\lambda^n,\\
a_0&=\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{-\log t}\,dt=\color{blue}{\log 2},\\
a_1&=-\frac12\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{-\log t}(t-\log t)\,dt=\color{blue}{-\frac14-\frac12\log\frac32},\\
a_2&=\frac{1}{12}\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{-\log t}(2t^2-3t\log t+\log^2 t)\,dt=\color{blue}{\frac{5}{48}+\frac16\log\frac43},\\
a_3&=-\frac{1}{24}\int_0^1\frac{1-t}{-\log t}(t^3-2t^2\log t+t\log^2 t)\,dt=\color{blue}{-\frac{11}{864}-\frac{1}{24}\log\frac54},
\end{align*}
and so on. For $m(k)$, use the power series of $e^{1/k}$, and [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) asymptotics of $H_k$...

Comment: This is brilliant thanks a ton. I never would have realized that we just need to use a simple substitution.